# My entities have only setters and getters but no methods - design failure -

Tags: c#, architecture, poco

I have read this once:

"Don't leave entities as bags of getters and setters and put their methods in another layer unless you have a good reason to"

My customer, order, ... objects just get the data from the SqlDataReaders. They have only getter and setter.

My first question is which design approach does this follow when someone implements methods in entities AND what are these methods doing?

Comment: Sounds like you are using objects as data models. That's fine for the most part. The general advice you have is to help avoid an antipattern called the god object, where one object contains every piece of logic for everything.

Comment: Sounds more like a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This way of thinking comes from the Domain Driven Design community.

In DDD you create a Domain Model that captures the functionality that your users request. You design your entities as having functionality and the data they need for it. You group them together in aggregates and you have separate classes that are responsible for construction (Factories) and querying (Repositories).

If you only have getters/setters you have an 'Anemic Domain Model'. Martin Fowler wrote about it in this [article](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html).

The problem with an Anemic Domain model is that you have the overhead of mapping your database to objects but not the benefits of it. If you don't use your entities as a real domain model, why don't you just use a DataTable or something for your data and keep your business logic in separate functions? An Anemic Domain model is an anti-pattern that should be avoided.

You also mention that you map the entities yourself. [This blog](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/07/24/dont-write-your-own-orm/) explains why using an Object-Relational Mapping tool can really help. If you use Entity Framework with a Code First approach you can write a clean domain model with both data and functionality and map it to your database without much hassle. Then you will have the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 1):

When you have methods as part of your model, you should only include model specific type of logic. For example, consider a bank account:

```
public class Account {
   public AccountId Id { get; set; }
   public Person Customer {get; set; }

   public void Credit(Money amount) { ... }
   public void Debit(Money amount) { ... } 

}
```

Credit and Debit are model-specific logic (you won't find them anywhere else in the application), and should be encapsulated in the Account class.

You also mentioned that you used SqlDataReader within your model classes to get the data from the database. This is a big anti-pattern. Here are some problems you will encounter with this:

1. Violating Single Responsibility Principle - The model is now in-charge of representing the data and getting the data from the db.
2. How about querying children in your model? It gets messy.
3. You won't be able to change your data-access as easily.

Keep the model lean. Put the data access logic in a repository, i.e. AccountRepository.